# Getting exception 'read' while iterating csv.reader object

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Please find this part of code.

```
with open('/tmp/'+file_n, 'wb') as f:
            print("----Heee")
            s3_client.download_fileobj('dev-itr-uls-weekly-files', key, f)
            data = reader(f)
            for row in data:
                        print("Iterating")
                        curr_str = ""
```

It is not printing 'Iterating' but throws exception 'read'.No idea why its coming.Please help.

Comment: Show the proper error.

Comment: 'Read' is not an exception in Python, could you print the actual error message.

Comment: Though you are also trying to read from a file you opened in write mode.

Comment: You appear to be mixing-together the download of the file and the reading of the file. You might find it easier to use `download_file()` to download the file, then open the file for use with the CSVReader. Don't combine the two operations with the one file handler.